# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis with AWS Glue schema registry

Tags: registry, schema, aws-glue, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

How to configure spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis with AWS Glue schema registry for Avro schema. I didn't find any options in the documentation of binder-kinesis or spring-integration-aws. There is any workaround solution to enable the schema registry

Comment: How would you configure it for plain Kinesis client if there were no Spring on top? This way you would give me a clue what to expose for you from Spring perspective to make such a configuration easier from the binder.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for your replay. 
Got it from AWS docs: Schema Registry integration is only available with KPL v0.14.2 or later and with KCL v2.3 or later. Schema Registry integration with JSON data format is available with KPL v0.14.8 or later and with KCL v2.3.6 or later. 
Once Spring-integration-aws moved to newer version of KPL/KCL, may be exposed as per document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry-integrations.html

Comment: Cool! Just create, please, a GH issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues, so we won't forget this feature once we have moved to AWS SDK v2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/155. Thanks

Comment: Any luck with the implementation? I’m looking for similar implementation examples.